# Can PhantomJS function if there is not page opeend

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs

Will phantomjs close itself if there is no page opened on it? I have one really weird scenario, because I am running tests in tabs/pages and when tests are finished I close tab/page, and it looks like, as if there is no page opened, phantomjs kills it self.

Is that possible?

Comment: Does phantomjs have any limit on how many pages can it have opened?

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS exits either when you call `phantom.exit()` or an uncaught error happens. When no page is open, it will run indefinitely. Otherwise, it couldn't be used as a web server through its [web server module](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/).

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS can run in just the console with no other browser running.  This makes it ideal for CI systems and background processes.

Checkout:  http://phantomjs.org/headless-testing.html